# Can a microSD card with an USB adapter be used to flash a BIOS?

Tags: bios, usb-flash-drive, micro-sd-card, card-reader

Does it act the same way a USB flash drive does? And would it work with the option to update the BIOS via the current BIOS or the new feature motherboards have where a BIOS can be updated without a CPU, RAM or GPU being mounted or both?

Comment: “Does it act the same way a USB flash drive does?” Pretty confident it does. Honestly I would try this out and see how it proceeds. If it doesn’t work, cheap USB flash drives are all over the place. I realize some people might not have easy access to getting such new hardware, but still. USB flash drives are available in many places nowadays in the U.S. and Europe for example.

Comment: I've had one µXD cards in an adapter work for installing an OS, and yet another, of same type and brand, fail as boot device for same OS, yet it stored data perfectly. So, for some unknown reason, the answer is equivocal. Normally, I'd say experiment to see if it works, **but a bad *BIOS* upgrade can brick a PC**.

Answer (score 0):

You mean use a microSD card plus USB adapter to boot from and then flash a BIOS update? That'll work just like a normal USB stick.

You'll always need a CPU and RAM though. Whether a GPU is required or not depends on the BIOS features.